# Expect dropdown to have contents

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara

What is the easiest way to check that a dropdown has the options I want?

I'm using rails and rspec along with capybara

I'm trying to write a test along the lines of:

```
expect(menu).to have_contents(item1.name)
expect(menu).to have_contents(item2.name)
expect(menu).not_to have_contents(item3.name)
```

Comment: How do you want to check for the options? Are you fine with using the option text or does it have to be by name?

Comment: @JustinKo Those should be one and the same. The drop down options are the items names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it.. easier than I originally thought

```
expect(page).to have_select("drop_down_id", options: [item1.name, item2.name])
expect(page).not_to have_select("drop_down_id", options: item3.name)
```

Answer (score 10):

For me, the above doesn't work but the below does:

```
expect(page).to have_select("drop_down_id", :with_options => [item1.name, item2.name])
```

Note **with_options**, as opposed to **options**.

Comment: I wish whoever downvoted this had explained why. Coming up on this problem now, the accepted answer doesn't work but this does.